# wp_signon() does not authenticate user guidance needed

Tags: login

I use form to send POST request to a page and to login user with `wp_signon()` in order to authenticate user to my wordpress installation as described in WP documentation:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $_POST["user-login"];
$creds['user_password'] = $_POST["user-password"];
$creds['remember'] = true;

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

After this little piece of code I'm checking if user was logged in:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo "SUCCESS"; } else { echo "FAIL!"; }
```

But I got `FAIL!` all the time. Then after sniffing around I found this little trick:

```
wp_set_current_user( $user );
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo "SUCCESS"; } else { echo "FAIL!"; }
```

I've got `SUCCESS` on this one but when I leave this page I got `FAIL` again and again.

Can anyone explain me how to login user with `wp_signon()` without logging her out after page is changed or reloaded or whatever.

---

I've got desirable result when I go to `/wp_admin` and login with WP's default login form. I can navigate through every page of my WP site remaining logged-in all the time. But when I try to do this outside the default form I `FAIL`.

Guide me! PLEASE!

Comment: is your site have SSL, i mean your site's url scheme http or https ??

Comment: @Anjum actually I store it on my localhost with MAMP ... so my answer is `I don't know` ))

Comment: can you tell me how do you access your login page i mean your login page url, `http://localhost/login-page/` or `https://localhost/login-page/` ?

Comment: please post your custom login form code here, so ..

Comment: @Anjum I use just `http://localhost:8888/registration/` but if you try to hint on `wp_signon( $user, secure:true/false )` I've tried both and it didn't work. Anyway thanks.

Comment: post your registration page code here so i can solve your problem

Comment: @Anjum Here's it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/n51c4jhw)

Comment: form html code not found in your code

Comment: @Anjum sorry for this ... I've updated the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/n51c4jhw) please check

Comment: you've not user-login field in your form add a text input name user-login and also use `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` in form action attribute instead of `<? echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path('registration') ); ?>`

Comment: @Anjum as you can see on the pastebin `$user_login` and `$user_email` are the same `$_POST["user_email"]` and concerning the from action it's just the permalink to the same page so it actions itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally this is working for me on my local WP installation after replacing - with _ from input  attribute name and using full php start tags `<?php` instead of `<?` the final code is here copy and paste into your template.

```
<?php if ( isset($_POST["user_email"]) && isset($_POST["user_password"]) ) {

$user_login     = esc_attr($_POST["user_email"]);
$user_password  = esc_attr($_POST["user_password"]);
$user_email     = esc_attr($_POST["user_email"]);

$user_data = array(
    'user_login'    =>      $user_login,
    'user_pass'     =>      $user_password,
    'user_email'    =>      $user_email,
    'role'          =>      'student'
);

// Inserting new user to the db
//wp_insert_user( $user_data );

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $user_login;
$creds['user_password'] = $user_password;
$creds['remember'] = true;

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

$userID = $user->ID;

wp_set_current_user( $userID, $user_login );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $userID, true, false );
do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );

}

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : echo 'SUCCESS'; ?>
<h1>Html for logged in user </h1>
<?php else : echo 'FAIL!'; ?>
<form id="user-credentials" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <p><input name="user_email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /></p>
    <p><input name="user_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" class="button blue size-s" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It keeps you logged in when you go to a page different from the one with the form? where `wp_set_current_user();` is set?

Comment: yes it's working fine for me, check your browser's cookie settings

Comment: I've checked cookies in all the browsers. It is enabled everywhere. When I use this code it logins user only when form sends POST request. When the page is reloaded without sending anything to itself no one is logged in. I tried `global $current_user; var_dump($current_user);` and I got user info dumped only when the POST was sent otherwise it returns `object(WP_User)#206 (7) { ["data"]=> NULL ["ID"]=> int(0) ...`

Comment: also when I login through **default WP login form** with the same user I've got `$current_user` var_dumped correctly in both cases. What is wrong with me??!!

Comment: are you calling both `wp_insert_user()` and `wp_signon()` on each request? if yes try to comment out `wp_insert_user()` and then login to see the result.

Comment: I've put the template files on the remote server and it works. Sorry for bothering you so long ... it was my mistake all along. Seems like `wp_signon();` works as expected

Comment: i think the problem in your WordPress installation try to re install on your local server.

Answer (score 0):

If your password includes the # and/or @ characters, you need to urlencode before sending in the form, and then urldecode before setting the credentials in wp_signon.

The url encoding for @ is %40, # is %23 and ! is %21

if your password is mY!p@ssWord# then should be URL encoded before POSTING to mY%21p%40ssWord%23, then URL decoded before setting the credentials for wp_signon